# Matlab to Numpy translation - matrix + scalar differences

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to translate a Matlab script into Numpy. This is part of the Matlab code:

```
function [idx,D]=knnsearch(varargin)
[N,M] = size(Q);
L=size(R,1);
idx = zeros(N,K);
D = idx;
for k=1:N
    d=zeros(L,1);
    for t=1:M
        d=d+(R(:,t)-Q(k,t)).^2;
    end
    d(k)=inf;
    [D(k),idx(k)]=min(d);
end
```

where `Q` and `R` are matrices that can be considered e.g. as `eye(5)`; you can consider `K = 1`. An example function call could be:

```
Q = eye(5);
R = eye(5);

[idx,D] = knnsearch(Q,R,1);
```

which returns:

```
idx:      
 2
 1
 1
 1
 1
D:
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
```

This is the Numpy code:

```
import numpy as np
def knnsearch(Q, R, K):
    (N,M) = Q.shape
    L = len(R[:,1])    
    idx = np.zeros((N,K), dtype=int)
    D = np.copy(idx)
    for k in range(0, N):
        d = np.zeros((L, 1))
        for t in range(0, M):
            d = d + (R[:,t] - Q[k,t])**2
        d[k] = np.inf
        idx[k] = np.argmin(d)
        D[k] = np.amin(d)
    return (idx, D)
```

where

```
Q0 = np.identity(5)
R0 = np.identity(5)

idxout, Dout = knnsearch(Q0, R0, 1)
```

This returns different from Matlab:

```
idx: 
[[5]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]
D: 
[[0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]]
```

There is a problem with the row number 9. The second part of the row, the scalar (`(R(:,t)-Q(k,t)).^2`), returns the same values for both Matlab and Numpy. Instead, the addition (`d` + scalar) returns different values. So, the matrix `d` contains different values in Matlab and Numpy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can only be answered with a [mcve]

Comment: ok, I've updated the question, now the code is complete

Comment: Such questions should include a small reproducible data set and your desired data set...

Comment: @spookyisland it is undoubtedly not complete, as I am not able to copy paste it and run it without making up data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `(R[:,t] - Q[k,t])**2` in Python creates a list with the length 5, but what you need is an array with the dimension `5x1`. To get this you simply need to replace

```
d = d + (R[:,t] - Q[k,t])**2
```

with

```
ma = (R[:,t] - Q[k,t])**2
ma.shape += (1,)
d = d + ma
```

Then you get the expected output:

```
idx: 
[[1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]]
D:
[[2]
 [2]
 [2]
 [2]
 [2]]
```

Comment: thank you, it works now!! and thanks for editing and improving my question